# How to specify column types in python polars.read_csv()

Tags: python, pandas, csv, python-polars

While reading a csv file in pandas, we have option of dtype in read_csv().
Do we have similar option in polars?

```
import pandas as pd
import polars as pl

data_pd = pd.read_csv('file.csv',dtype={'col1':str, 'col2':str})
data_pl = pl.read_csv('file.csv',dtype={'col1':str, 'col2':str})
```

**I get error:**

TypeError: read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dtype'

Comment: Did you try covering the passing the dictionary value within quotes just for polars.read_csv (not for pandas)?

Comment: its `dtypes` and not `dtype` . https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.read_csv.html

Comment: Also, you should probably use polars data types (as the docs say `PolarsDataType`) - see [the docs](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/datatypes.html).

Answer (score 3):

the right way of choosing the data types when reading a CSV is using `dtypes`, as mentioned in some of the comments.

Here is an example of how to use it:

```
df = pl.read_csv('file.csv', dtypes=[pl.Utf8,pl.Utf8])
```